# Importing android projects that do not have android manifest file

Tags: android, import

I am currently busy in designing a custom view for my major project. I ran through custom view tutorial provided at developer.android.com . I downloaded the associated sharable project because it gets easy to handle and understand the mechanism of the application when source code is in front of you. To my surprise, the project only contains two folders, src and res and there was no android-manifest file. I tried normal import method, import from existing code and createing new project from exsting android code, no luck with any of the methods. Here the link for the [project.](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/CustomView.zip)

Can somebody please explain to me how I can get it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new empty android project. Copy all resources and source files to your project folder.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html.

Goto AndroidManifest.xml define activities and permissions accordingly.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="package name"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="packagename.MainActivity"//your mainactivity
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
       <activity
        android:name="packagename.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="packagename.SecondActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: It appears CommonsWare beat you to it.

Comment: i was about put the same answer as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

> Can somebody please explain to me how I can get it working ?

Create an empty Android project. Copy in the `res/` and `src/` from the ZIP file. Modify the manifest to point to the activity class that you copied from the ZIP file.

Comment: I once had tried this method with another project and ran into some big problems possibly due to my own ignorance. Thanks.